# Extracting text from html?

Tags: php

I have a string as below

```
<p>&nbsp;Hello World, this is StackOverflow&#39;s question details page</p>
```

I want to extract text from above HTML as `Hello World, this is StackOverflow's question details page` notice that I want to remove the `&nbsp;` as well.

How we can achieve this in PHP, I tried few functions, strip_tags, html_entity_decode etc, but all are failing in some conditions.

Please help, Thanks!

**Edited** my code which I am trying is as below, but its not working :( It leaves the `&nbsp;` and `&#39;` this type of characters.

```
$TMP_DESCR = trim(strip_tags($rs['description']));
```

Comment: What conditions, don't leave us guessing!?

Comment: as @jakenoble says would help if you posted your sample code & output & errors.

Comment: If the shown string is part of a full HTML page or a larger snippet containing additional markup, please see [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: guys added my code, please check!

Comment: @Gordon its not a big html, I just want to do it with simple methods :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below worked for me...had to do a `str_replace` on the non-breaking space though.

```
$string = "<p>&nbsp;Hello World, this is StackOverflow&#39;s question details page</p>";
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(trim(strip_tags(str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $string))), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: yes, that's working for me as well. If there is no solution for `&nbsp;` then its fine, we can go with replace. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` will get rid of the tags, and `trim()` should get rid of the whitespace. I'm not sure if it will work with non-breaking spaces though.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to call trim() on the HTML to remove the white space. http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Then `strip_tags`, then `html_entity_decode`.

So: `html_entity_decode(strip_tags(trim(html)));`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the nicest and most reliable way to do this is with genuine (X|HT)ML parsing functions like the `DOMDocument` class:

```
<?php

$str = "<p>&nbsp;Hello World, this is StackOverflow&#39;s question details page</p>";

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $str));

echo trim($dom->firstChild->nodeValue);
// "Hello World, this is StackOverflow's question details pages"
```

This is probably slight overkill for this problem, but using the proper parsing functionality is a good habit to get into.

---

**Edit**: You can reuse the `DOMDocument` object, so you only need two lines within the loop:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // or whatever
    $dom->loadHTML(str_replace('&nbsp;', ' ', $rs['description']));
    $TMP_DESCR = $dom->firstChild->nodeValue;

    // do something with $TMP_DESCR
}
```

Comment: seems a long method and as I am running a loop, so I think this will be extensive.